# A.E.I.O That means you. What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Billy Crystal and John Goodman’s song from “Monsters’ Inc.”, “If I Didn’t  Have You”, is closed with the word:

> A-E-I-O That means you Yeah!

What does A-E-I-O mean? Why does it mean “you”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AEIOU is the order of the English vowels and is something commonly learned/recited by schoolchildren. The song is just making a little joke on the fact that "you" sounds like the letter "U".